# Count hashtag frequency in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to count the frequency of hashtag words in the 'text' column of my dataframe.

```
index        text
1            ello ello ello ello #hello #ello
2            red green blue black #colours
3            Season greetings #hello #goodbye 
4            morning #goodMorning #hello
5            my favourite animal #dog
```

```
word_freq = df.text.str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts()
```

The above code will perform a frequency count on all strings in the text column, but I just to return the hashtag frequencies.

For example after running the code on my dataframe above, it should return

```
#hello        3
#goodbye      1
#goodMorning  1
#ello         1
#colours      1
#dog          1
```

Is there a way of slightly re-jigging my word_freq code so it only counts hashtag words and returns them in the way I put above? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include [`Minimal, Reproducible Example`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/4985099)

Comment: did you try to filter words in cells and keep only words which starts with `#` ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. The rules require you to show you tried to adapt the code yourself, and post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This has no MCVE. You can't just post a spec of what code you want written for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) on column `text` to find all hashtag words then use [`Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) + [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
counts = df['text'].str.findall(r'(#\w+)').explode().value_counts()
```

Another idea using [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) + [`DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
s = df['text'].str.split(expand=True).stack()
counts = s[lambda x: x.str.startswith('#')].value_counts()
```

Result:

```
print(counts)
#hello          3
#dog            1
#colours        1
#ello           1
#goodMorning    1
#goodbye        1
Name: text, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

one way using [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) that would remove the `#` from the result. Then `value_counts` as well

```
s = df['text'].str.extractall('(?<=#)(\w*)')[0].value_counts()
print(s)
hello          3
colours        1
goodbye        1
ello           1
goodMorning    1
dog            1
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly detailed solution but this does the trick.

```
dictionary_count=data_100.TicketDescription.str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts().to_dict()

dictionary_count={'accessgtgtjust': 1,
'sent': 1,
'investigate': 1,
'edit': 1,
'#prd': 1,
'getting': 1}

ert=[i for i in list(dictionary_count.keys()) if '#' in i]

ert
Out[238]: ['#prd']

unwanted = set(dictionary_count.keys()) - set(ert)

for unwanted_key in unwanted: 
   del dictionary_count[unwanted_key]

dictionary_count
Out[241]: {'#prd': 1}
```