# Python count hashtag per platform

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, text, pandas-groupby

My data is organized in a data frame with the following structure

```
| ID       | Post                | Platform    | 

| -------- | ------------------- | ----------- |

| 1        | Something #hashtag1 | Twitter     |

| 2        | Something #hashtag2 | Insta       |

| 3        | Something #hashtag1 | Twitter     |
```

I have been able to extract and count the hashtag using the following (using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63228403/count-hashtag-frequency-in-a-dataframe)):

```
df.Post.str.extractall(r'(\#\w+)')[0].value_counts().rename_axis('hashtags').reset_index(name='count')
```

I am now trying to count hashtag operation occurrence from each platform. I am trying the following:

```
df.groupby(['Post', 'Platform'])['Post'].str.extractall(r'(\#\w+)')[0].value_counts().rename_axis('hashtags').reset_index(name='count')
```

But, I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Answer (score 1):

We can solve this easily using 2 steps.Assumption each post has just single hashtag

```
    Step 1: Create a new column with Hashtag
    df['hashtag']= df.Post.str.extractall(r'(\#\w+)')[0].reset_index()[0]

    Step 2: Group by and get the counts
    df.groupby([ 'Platform']).hashtag.count()
```

**Generic Solutions Works for any number of hashtag**
We can solve this easily using 2 steps.

```
    # extract all hashtag
    df1  = df.Post.str.extractall(r'(\#\w+)')[0].reset_index()
    # Ste index as index of original tagle where hash tag came from
    df1.set_index('level_0',inplace = True)


    df1.rename(columns={0:'hashtag'},inplace = True)

    df2 = pd.merge(df,df1,right_index = True, left_index = True)

   df2.groupby([ 'Platform']).hashtag.count()
```

Comment: This is a great starting point. The number of rows in `df2` increases as it creates multiple rows for posts that had more than 1 hashtag. It would be great to create a wide dataframe instead of a long one.

Comment: Agreed, but dont you think if we did wide transformation will increase complexity mutifold